# react-router-dom Build Giving 404 When Accessing URL Directly, But Not In Development

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app created with create-react-app and am using react-router-dom for routing.

The general layout is:

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <BodyContent />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Bodycontent.js

```
        <Fragment>
            <Navigation/>
            <main>
                <ScrollToTopRoute path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
                <ScrollToTopRoute path="/page1" exact component={Page1}/>
                    <ScrollToTopRoute path="/page1/page2" exact component={Page2}/>
                <ScrollToTopRoute path="/page3" exact component={Page3}/>
               ... etc...


            </main>
        </Fragment>
```

The ScrollToTopRoute is simply an extension of the standard router functionality that ensures new pages scroll back to the top for a good UX.

ScrollToTop.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-5477132-2');



class ScrollToTopRoute extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.path === this.props.location.pathname && this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
            console.log("Triggered");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

        return <Route {...rest} render={props => (<Component {...props} />)} />;
    }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTopRoute);
```

In development the app works as expected, all routes work and if you go directly to a URL like `localhost:3000/page1` it will load correctly. I have built the site using yarn build and deployed to a typical VPS. The website and internal links to components/routes all work as expected, however when accessing a URL directly as above such as `www.theurl.com/page1` it will 404 and I am at a loss as to why the outcome is different.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the underlying reason for this is actually due to how your server is configured.
 `React Router` can only handle routing after your front-end scripts have been loaded (from the index page), which isn't the case when a user hits the `/foo` deeplink route in production.

You'll have to set your server up to return the index page on every route request *except* for **api** routes that need to be handled by the server.

This should set your server up to let React Router handle deeplink requests.

If you're using Node and Express it should look something like this:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('public/index.html')
})
```

Let me know if I can explain further.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the lead. I'm actually very new to Node and React and this project was my first production attempt so I'm still quite new to it all (however quite experienced with the typical LAMP stack). The application is a typical create-react-app structure and I'm not using Express. The server has node installed, so I'm just unsure where I would add your suggested lines.

Comment: Sure! Do you have the ability to use Express with Node or is there a reason for not doing so? Express is a very simple and lean framework for setting up a web server in the Node runtime. It's really the only framework that I prefer to use because it's easy and reliable. If you can, I'm happy to help you set it up!

Comment: I have the ability to use Express. I've played with it a little in a dev project running a backend API to talk to mysql and return content to a frontend react app however again, I'm not super experienced with it. Is the theory to install express in the react app or run a separate backend API for route handling?

Comment: So the theory is to install express on a backend API, and handle the backend API routes in express. React Router should handle the front-end routing, and services like Axios handle requests to the back-end routes. Basically anytime a request to view your site is sent to your server, respond with the index.html file - this will run the script files and set up React-Router on the front-end. The problem that's occurring is when a user tries to hit `www.example.com/deeplink` your server isn't sending the index file so React Routing is not being set up.

Comment: No routes on your server are set up to handle that `/deeplink` route, so the 404 error is being generated. If you tell all requests for routes that you expect React Router to handle to return with the `index.html` file (where your script files are being run - setting up react router), then React Router should handle the deeplinks while still allowing you to request data from a back-end API.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. fixed it by adding a htaccess file with following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

found the solution at: [How to fix "404" error when directly accessing a component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248347/how-to-fix-404-error-when-directly-accessing-a-component-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

If you created an app using create-react-app you can use this solution. Create a file called **"_redirects"** (Note: file name is just _redirects without any extension) in your **build** folder. Then write the below content in that file:

```
/*    /index.html  200
```

Reupload your build folder again, and this issue should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent solution for Nginx is:

```
    location / {
        # other config here
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
```