# .htaccess Rewrite for React using React Router

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite or add to my existing .htaccess file so that my hosting service (Hostinger) can use a single index.html file for all pages instead of trying to fetch a new file server-side. I am using React with React-Router and it does not understand how to use the paths correctly.

Existing File:

This was used to fix an issue with my SSL

========================== File ===========================

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.matthewendicott.space/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.matthewendicott.space/$1 [L,R=301]
```

====================== Testing and Similar Issues ==============

Here are a few things that I have tried:

https://hostpapasupport.com/set-301-permanent-redirect-using-htaccess/

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file

And here is a similar issue:

[How to fix "404" error when directly accessing a component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248347/how-to-fix-404-error-when-directly-accessing-a-component-in-react?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If anyone needs help with this I was able to work with a friend of mine at Hostinger and here is what your .htaccess file will need to include.

Copy and paste exactly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried the exact same code and it work fine on the first look. but if we reload the page or visit a page directly from the URL. it gives out ERROR 404.

Comment: That's weird, I cannot replicate that issue

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

In my case `.htaccess` didn't work. I had to change Apache virtual host file and now it works fine.

```
    <Directory /var/private/test-site/dream-list/build/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

        # ADDING FOLLOWING LINES SOLVED THE PROBLEM
        RewriteEngine on
        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

    </Directory>
```