# VueRouter navigation to hash without # symbol?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using `router-link` to navigate over my `Vue/Laravel8` `single page app`:

```
  <router-link :to="{ hash: 'about' }">About us</router-link>
```

This method unfortunately leaves an ugly `#` symbol in the `url`:

```
localhost:3000/#about
```

Is ther any conventient way to get rid of the `#`?^

**Edit:**

It was suggested to use `history mode` but this is a `router link to hash`. I have `history mode` enabled already but it doesn't remove the `#` from the url.

**`router.js`**:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Home from "../vue/home";
import About from "../vue/about";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter ({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {path: "/", name: "home", component: Home},
        {path: "/about", name: "about", component: About},
    ],
    scrollBehavior(to) {
        return {
            selector: to.hash,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        }
    }
});
```

**`web.php`**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 2):

`#` means hash router, the hash router doesn't require HTML5 history API, which is convenient when you can't redirect every request to `/index.html` when you're building a single-page web app.

What you are looking for is `BrowserRouter`, which requires using HTML5 history API and requires you to redirect every request to `/index.html` in order to work, because it's a client router, not from a server.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

Simply add `mode: 'history'` and you're using `BrowserRouter` now.

More: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @JosephWhang please see the `edit` section.

Answer (score 1):

You would actually just want to set `mode` to `history`:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history'
})
```

make sure your server is configured to handle these links,though:

[history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Answer (score 0):

No. The hash sign is **essential** for using hash mode (hence why it is in the name). It indicates the start of the fragment identifier (which is used for in-page navigation).

If you didn't use the hash, then you've be using HTML5 history mode and navigating to a different *path* which would need to be handled by the server.

(As an aside, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69237467/19068) which covers a similar question from the opposite direction for React).