# ReactJS Router does not work on build version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using ReactJs with react-router-dom for my website. The developer build on my localhost works great. localhost:3000/register takes me to the registration page. But in the build version created with `npm run build`, the myIp/register page takes me to a file not found page, but not the one I added in the App.js. The home path works when I enter my ip as url.
App.js:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/Style.css';
import './css/Register.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import Register from './pages/Register';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My package.json: (with the version information)

```json
{
  "name": "my_page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Has someone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Generally, apache, nginx, such web servers are required for route settings.

Comment: You have to configure your server to redirect 404 to index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint with the server config. So I was able to find a working solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59630881/12411687

Simply place the following .htaccess file in the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```